# Matlab: Publish figures in a sequence

Tags: matlab, publish, matlab-figure

Kindly consider the published output in the attached image. Is it possible to arrange figures in a order, say for example: figure below one another? I searched, but couldn't resolve it.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: As a workaround, you might want to use `subplot` to arrange the axes within one figure window.

Comment: that could be one option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could/should use "snapnow" instead of creating figures to get pictures in a well-defined order.

Comment: You can change the ordering. Chaning the position is not easily possible